# Docker command can't connect docker daemon using Hypriot Docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, hypriot

I installed Docker for RPi from Hypriot.

When I first run `systemctl -l status docker` I get this response:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2016-06-13 06:32:50 UTC; 18min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1327 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1327 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

After `sudo service docker start` and running `systemctl -l status docker` again, I get this response:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-06-13 06:52:55 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1434 (docker)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1434 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --storage-driver=overlay -D
```

"Horray! It is working, I am running Docker on my RPi lets pull an image!!!"

`docker pull resin/rpi-raspbian`, but:

```
Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Okey, so this might have solved my issue (see link below). Don't know about the versions on hypriot-docker though, but I will look it up :)

https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/Get-Docker-up-and-running-on-the-RaspberryPi-(ARMv6)-in-three-steps

Answer (score 0):

I used some faulty instructions on how to install using `apt-get`. The instructions in the link below do work, but I am not sure about the hypriot-docker versions though.

https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/Get-Docker-up-and-running-on-the-RaspberryPi-(ARMv6)-in-three-steps

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue I when I forgot to run my Docker commands with sudon.

The error is happening because you don't have permission to access the socket Docker is listening on unless you are root or are in the "docker" group.